# Sharepoint NewForm redirect with ID

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

When I add a new item to a list, on save I need to redirect to another form with item ID value that was just added. sending it through URL. I have seen posts of how to do that from edit form or display form where the id already there. but this is from the newform. thank you in advanced.

Update: 
Or If this is hard, how can I get the last ID in that list?

Comment: can you explain what you are trying to achieve? What other form do you want to open? What is the information flow?

Comment: I am trying to go to another form that should use the just new created id. I know how to use the id as long as I can pass it on the URL. If this is hard, how can I get the last ID. I can then do id+1. thanks

Comment: What other form do you want to go to? A form in a different list? A form in the same list? Open a new form? Please explain what you are trying to achieve. As in: The bigger picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this solution here. You just need to change the listname.
http://sympmarc.com/2009/06/12/redirect-to-another-page-from-newform-aspx-with-the-new-items-id/